# Generate a CIL executable not EXE then execute it

Tags: c#, .net, cil

I have a c# project that generates an EXE file. Now, I'm in a "secure" corporate environment, where I can compile my project, but I cannot execute the EXE file.

As a Java programmer, I'm wondering if there is not a way to compile the c# project into something that would not be an EXE file, but a CIL file and then execute the CIL file by something that corresponds to java.exe in the dotnet world.

EDIT in response to comments:

1. I can run exe files that have been installed by a package manager
2. Yes, I know the corporate policy is stupid.

Comment: You can't run exe files? How do you do *anything*?

Comment: You can work around this issue, but you shouldn't want to. Explain to the organisation that you can't do your work with ridiculous environment limitations in place.

Comment: I cannot run exe files that are not installed by a package manager. I cannot bring my own exe files.

Comment: I thought our company blocking youtube was bad.

Comment: Then you can't develop software using C#. I'd ask my boss rather than here.

Comment: Well, I absolutely prefer to talk to the compiler than to my organization. The compiler is probably way more intelligent. If there is a workaround, I want to use it ;)

Comment: As a workaround, consider quitting your job.

Comment: Fortunately, this is just a tiny part of my job. I need to execute this crap and then move on to a sane environment of my office (where EXE files cannot be executed either, because everything is Linux :) ). But I need a constructive work-around, a big thank you in advance to anyone, who has one.

Comment: I would then implement the UI using Web tech instead of an EXE

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster. What I take away from you answer is that there is no way to simply generate the CLI code,  without the EXE wrapper, and execute the CLI code by an "interpreter" a'la java.exe .. Also, your workaround needs me to get additional approvals from the company, which is what I need to avoid. (sorry, this is aresponse to a comment that has disappeared in between)

Comment: Does the application need to run on the system itself, or would a web interface suffice? Does the target system have interpreters, such as Perl or Python, installed? ... How valuable is your time to the company - that is, how much is it worth to them to find a workaround to this 'problem', instead of changing the policy?

Comment: the app needs to run on the system. i guess i can get a perl package if it would help

Comment: well, as for the value of my time. this c# thing is a parr of a larger system, that should go into testing at thw end of may. by experience, requests of this kind take ages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this should be pretty easy.

.NET executables are simply DLLs like any other - the main difference being the executable format itself, and the fact that EXE files have an entry point, while DLLs don't.

It also means that you can load the EXE into memory exactly the same way as you would with a DLL:

```
Assembly.LoadFrom("SomeExe.exe");
```

You're already half way there - now we just need to find and execute the entry point. And unsurprisingly, this is *also* pretty trivial:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("SomeExe.exe");
assembly.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, null);
```

For most applications, this should work perfectly fine; for some, you'll have to make sure the thread you're using to invoke the entry point has `STAThread` or `MTAThread` respectively (`Thread.TrySetThreadApartment` if you're starting a new thread).

It might need tweaking for some applications, but it shouldn't be too hard to  fix.

So you can just make some bootstrap application ("interpreter") that only really contains these two lines of code. If you can't get even that approved, and you really need something as an "official package", try some .NET application that allows you to execute arbitrary code - for example, LINQPad, or PowerShell.

**EDIT:**

This does have limitations, of course, and it does introduce some extra setup work:

- The bootstrapper has to target the same or higher version of .NET Framework. .NET Portable might be particularly tricky, but I assume you have that well under control. It also has to have the same bitness (if specified explicitly).
- You need to run the debugging through the bootstrapper. That actually isn't all too hard - just go to project properties, debug and select "Start external program".
- The bootstrapper has to run under full trust conditions - it's necessary for reflection to work. On most systems, this simply means you have to have the exe as a local file (e.g. not from a network share). Tools like LINQPad will run under full trust by default.
- The application must not depend on `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly`. This isn't used all that often, so it shouldn't be a problem. Quite a few similar issues should also be fine since you build the application you're trying to run yourself.

Comment: And which executable will run the `Assembly.Load("SomeExe.exe")`? OP cannot run arbitrary executables on his environment. And how will you debug `SomeExe.exe`? How will you start it from Visual Studio?

Comment: @CodeCaster Any application that allows you to execute some C# code. And it's pretty easy to debug `SomeExe.exe`, as well as start it from VS automatically.

Comment: In case you missed it: OP's PC is heavily locked down by company policy. He can write and compile an executable from Visual Studio, but not start it. So again, with this "bootstrapper" in place (given he gets it approved), how will he run this bootstrapper from Visual Studio while allowing debugging? (Yes, I know it's possible, I'm asking if you can tell how). OP should simply not want to do this. It may get the executable running in the end, but it's such a counterproductive environment that OP should take this down from the root: just allow his machine to run random executables.

Comment: @CodeCaster The approach is pretty simple - you change the start action to "Start external program". That's all you need. You will have full debugging faculties as if you didn't use the bootstrapper, including stuff like Edit and Continue. You could even attach the debugger after starting the application manually, if needed - the debugging information is still there (though you'll get some optimizations that can make debugging somewhat trickier). And yeah, of course he should figure it out with his management - but that doesn't make this answer any less useful (especially to other people).

Comment: @DavidVonka The PowerShell approach might be tricky in that you'll need to make sure it executes in full trust - otherwise you can't use reflection. And I haven't actually tried it (unlike the LINQPad option - and you should get LINQPad anyway, it's an awesome small-prototyping tool for .NET), there might be some issues with being a part of a hosted environment. You might need to spawn a new `AppDomain` with a new thread and everything.

Comment: I understand, and I know, I just mean if you can edit that into your answer to make it more complete. You'll also need to pass the full or relative path to the executable-under-debug, you'll need to ensure the bootstrapper and executable target the same framework and platform, and so on. I just mean you're not quite there with just those two lines. Upvoted nonetheless. :)

Comment: thanks, everyone. I'm going to try this out right now. For your information, I have also started the formal process to get the obstacle removed.

Comment: ok, the machine in question has powershell on it - no need to ask anyone to install anything, which would be a problem with linqpad. I fired up powershell and go like [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("c:\users\.....\bin\Debug\mstr.exe") and the response is an BadImageFormatException and a textual error message saying the same thing, that I have tried to load something in a bad format.

Comment: @DavidVonka Right, that means the executable has newer version of .NET framework, or a different bitness. Are you launching 32-bit or 64-bit Powershell? What .NET Framework and bitness are you targeting?

Comment: I ended up actually calling **[Namespace.Classname]::Main()** instead of the invoke construct.

Comment: @DavidVonka Yeah, that works fine if you know the assembly at compile-time - so it's fine for PowerShell, which always knows :)